# KIWI TCMS change time zone settings

Tags: datetime, networking, bolt-cms, kiwi, tiki-wiki

**How to change timezone settings on the kiwi tcms dashboard?
Facing issue while executing the test run**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Timezone in KiwiTCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811728/setting-timezone-in-kiwitcms)

Answer (score 2):

Kiwi TCMS and Tiki Wiki are different. Please remove the Tiki Wiki tag. ;-)